# RealmSwift crashes with error "Invalid property name" after update

Tags: ios, swift, realm, ios12

I just updated a project to Swift 5.0 and updated Realm and RealmSwift from 2.8.3 to 3.14.2.

The project ran fine before, but now it is crashing on the following simple example:

Definition:

```
class Subscription : Object {

    dynamic var expiryDate = Date()
    dynamic var productId = Product.SubscriptionID
}
```

Implementation:

```
let query = NSPredicate(format:"productId == %@", productId)
let subs = Array(realm.objects(Subscription.self).filter(query))
```

with the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid property name', reason: 'Property 'productId' not found in object of type 'Subscription''
```

Has anything changed with RealmSwift that would cause these errors?

Comment: `dynamic var productId = Product.SubscriptionID` - what is this? How is `Product` defined?

Comment: struct Product {
        static let SubscriptionID = "com.company.appName”
}

Comment: Object fields should have `@objc` declarations - add those on and retry.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisShaw, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow all the examples in the Realm documentation you'll see that all fields are declared as both `@objc` and `dynamic`. If you therefore change your definitions as below the problem should resolve:-

```
class Subscription : Object {

  @objc dynamic var expiryDate = Date()
  @objc dynamic var productId = Product.SubscriptionID
}
```